# Names on user cards above moderator messages are wrongly wrapped

Tags: bug, responsive-design, user-card, moderator-messages

On narrower screens, like an iPhone 11, the names on user cards above moderator messages are sometimes wrapped in strange places, like this:

[image]

Comment: Good to see you're putting that diamond to good use :P 6-8 year suspension, eh? ;)

Comment: Where should the name be wrapped? Or should it not be wrapped at all...?

Comment: @bobble at a space, if there is any. I don't know what happens with longer names.

Comment: I may or may not have believed that was a legitimate moderator message before reaching the end.. :)

Comment: That message comes across as very amusingly passive aggressive when the suspension length is that long! "We get it, it happens... if a misunderstanding, no harm done! We've temporarily suspended your account. You may return after 6-8.... ***years***. :)"

Comment: Why doesn't your account page look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYfIM.png), then? ;)

Comment: That's an interesting bug Glorfinde :)

Comment: Yeah, @zcoop98, we usually try to edit the default template when we're sending someone off for 1 year based on repeated offenses of rude/abusive behavior.